# python flask code change not reflecting in application using gunicorn - systemd

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python environment and I developed the initialization of python with flask and with some small functions. And I create the gunicorn.service and gunicorn.socket in systemd and connect it to the nginx by unix socket. Its running successfully. But the issue is If we change the code like php or node (with pm2 watcher) it can't changed the code while we running the app. This case I can only see the changes after i run the `systemctl restart gunicorn` command. otherwise its not display the changed codes

My wsgi.py

```
from app import app as application 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. In fact, when developing for flask you should run it in development mode which will pick up on your changes and restart the app.

```
export FLASK_APP=app
$ flask run
```

There are some good examples in the [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)

Comment: How we run export FLASK_ENV=development in gunicorn

Comment: These are shell commands that you run from the terminal to launch flask in development mode. The first one sets an environment variable and the second runs flask built-in dev server. This is for development only and will support refreshing your app as you do code changes so you don't need gunicorn. To see changes with gunicorn you need to restart the app. This essentially what flask dev server is doing for you in development mode.